# Jpos java.net.SocketException

Tags: java, sockets, jpos

I have written a basic jpos client application  that is deployed on tomcat and it sends 8583 messages to a jpos server. The jpos server implementation has been working for a long time and it has other clients connected to it. The client jpos application that I wrote is  triggered by a  rest end point  and it works fine when the requests are executed serially. When the load is increased  by running multiple threads ,I see the below exceptions in logs. Any idea what might be happening in this case?

Code

```
class JposClient{

private CSChannel csChannel;

public ISOMsg send(ISOMsg request){
ISOMsg response
csChannel=getCSChannel();
csChannel.connect();
jposChannel.send(request);
do {
    response = jposChannel.receive();
    }while(response.getMTI().startsWith("08"));

}

return response;

}

private CSChannel getCSChannel() throws IOException {
    
        if(csChannel!=null){
return csChannel;
}
        try {
            csChannel = new CSChannel();
            Configuration configuration = new SimpleConfiguration();
            configuration.put("keep-alive", "true");
            configuration.put("expect-keep-alive", "true");
            configuration.put("host", "127.0.0.1");
            configuration.put("port", String.valueOf(5456));
            csChannel.setConfiguration(configuration);
            csChannel.setPackager(new GenericPackager(
                "packager.xml"););
        } catch (ISOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return csChannel;
    }

}
```

Logs

```
java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
        at java.net.Socket.getInputStream(Socket.java:921)
        at org.jpos.iso.BaseChannel.connect(BaseChannel.java:280)
        at org.jpos.iso.BaseChannel.connect(BaseChannel.java:414)
        at org.jpos.iso.BaseChannel.reconnect(BaseChannel.java:845)


java.io.EOFException: null
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:197)
        at org.jpos.iso.channel.CSChannel.getMessageLength(CSChannel.java:97)
        at org.jpos.iso.BaseChannel.receive(BaseChannel.java:712)
```